# Guava Interner misses some potential for performance improvement

Tags: java, performance, guava

I'm interested in Java object internalization. It seems that its difficult to provide a performant implementation that avoids pitfalls, so I'm inclined to use libraries. One option is `Interner` from Google Guava.  But it occured to me: doesn't that implementation miss some potential for performance improvement? (Guava misses something? Cannot be true. Most likely, I'm missing something here! Please enlight me.)

One advantage of object internalization is that object equality can be realized by pointer comparison, i.e., `a.equals(b)` is equivalent to `a == b`, which is much faster than equaliy based on field comparison. But an object to be internalized cannot implement its `boolean equals(Object b)` function as `return this == b`: the `Interner` library requires you to creat an object, which is then compared to the interned objects by the object's "real" `equals()` method (i.e., by comparing the object's fields). Only after internalization, `==` can be used.  A similar argument holds for `hash()`.

Now, I do not want to replace all `a.equals(b)` by `a == b` in my code.  (The functional equivalent would be `Objects.requireNonNull(a) && a == b` anyways.)  And for `hash()`, there is no such "trick".  Therefore, you pay the price for internalization but you do not get the full advantage of it.

How could things be improved?  Provide an interface `Internalizable` that defines two methods `boolean realEquals(Object other)` and `int realHash()`. When planning to internalize objects of a certain class, make that class implement `Internalizable` and rename `equals()` and `hash()` accordingly. The `Interner`, requiring its objects to implement that interface, would use a special implementation of `WeakHashMap` (or like) that uses these methods instead of `equals()` and `hash()`.

Comment: It's worth noting that the typical motivation for interning is saving memory, not pointer equality (though potentially-faster `.equals()` behavior is a nice side-effect). A well-behaved class should work correctly even if compared against another instance that wasn't interned. In some cases you can go further and enforce *only* reference-equality, but this is a tradeoff, since it puts a high burden on the class implementation to prevent leaks of equivalent instances. `Interner` didn't want to make that tradeoff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even the call of a virtual `equals` method (containing a `==` comparison) is less performant than comparing directly by `==`. I suggest you replace the `equals` methods.

Yet if there is a reason you cannot do this safely: Good equals methods (and those generated by IDEs) start with some short circuit returns, e.g.

```
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    MyObject other = (MyObject) obj;
```

Such an `equals` methods should be nearly as performant as you expect.

Comment: And what about `hash`? You could add a field to store a previously computed hash value in.  But that wastes memory and looks clumsy.

Comment: I do not see where you need `hashCode()`. If you want to put your object as keys into a HashMap: Use `IdentityHashMap`. I never encountered a call to `hashCode` outside of a HashMap.